# How convert a MySQL test case to a c/c++ source code file?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, testcase

Supposed that I have a MySQL test case mytest.test. Here are its contents:

```
use test;
create table t(id int, name varchar(25)) engine = falcon;
insert into t values(1, "John");
insert into t values(2, "Edward");
drop table t;
```

Well it is easy to write a c/c++ source file to do what the test case does. Here is the c/c++ source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    MYSQL conn;
    mysql_init(&conn);

    mysql_real_connect(&conn,xxx,...);
    mysql_query(&conn, "create table t(id int, name varchar(25)) engine = falcon");
    mysql_query(&conn, "insert into t values(1, 'John')");
    mysql_query(&conn, "insert into t values(2, 'Edward')");
    mysql_query(&conn, "drop table t");
    mysql_close(&conn);
}
```

However, now, I have an interesting test case for MySQL. It is something like this:

```
--source include/have_falcon.inc

let $engine = 'Falcon';
eval SET @@storage_engine = $engine;

--disable_warnings
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
--enable_warnings

CREATE TABLE t(i int);
connect (conn1,localhost,root,,);

let $num=1000000;
while ($num)
{
   connection conn1;
   --send insert into t values(1);
   connection default;
   --send truncate table t;
   connection conn1;
   --reap
   connection default;
   --reap 
   dec $num;
}
DROP TABLE t;
```

As you see, there are some weird symbols, such as "connection default", "--send" and "--reap". I don't know what's the corresponding c/c++ source code of them. So Is there anyone can tell me how to convert them to proper c/c++ source code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `connection x;`, but is it just saying switch to a different connections?  In which case using two different `MYSQL` objects would do that?

Comment: Well, I am also confused with the 'connection' statement. Why does there need two connection targets?

Comment: Maybe it's connecting to two different databases? (a master / slave maybe, could be testing replication?)